# How to generate JSON string at runtime according to user input and basic logical rule?

Tags: java, json

There is a JSON template file:

```
{
    "name": "${name_input}",
    "age": "${age_input}",
    #if ${title_input} != ''
    "title": "title_input"
    #endif
}
```

The result file is generated at runtime according to input.

The json file is elasticsearch query dsl. Acturaly I need a ES-ORM just like Mybatis.

Comment: Can you provide some context? It's not very clear what have you tryied and what problems did you have... You can e.g. provide the piece of code you tryied to use the JSON template in... Did you tryied something like Freemarker Template Engine? https://freemarker.apache.org/

Comment: Or why not to just use Jackson.

Comment: Have you consider googling **java object to json**? You can create a data object and use Jackson annotations to not generate null value members?

Comment: Further question:  MyBatis - do you (need to) use that or was it just an example.  How? Also if this is an requirement, considder adding the MyBatis tag.

Comment: @Jerry Chou share which API are you using for json generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way will be to create a pojo. It is nothing but a normal object fill the values as per input and use either Gson or jackson to convert it in json

```
 Gson gson = new Gson(); // from google 
 String jsonStr = gson.toJson(yourObj) // converts into json string
```